# reading a json file in python

Tags: python, json

hi I want to read a JSON file in python and any kind of syntax that i use i receive an error and i don't know what to do the code :

```
import urllib
import pprint
import json
import re
import requests
import pprint

with open('synsets.json' , encoding = 'utf-8') as json_data:
    d = json.loads(json_data.read())
    json_data.close()
    pprint(d)
```

the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\markaz\wikiomega\code1.py", line 13, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_data.read())
  File "C:\Users\BehnaM1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\BehnaM1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\BehnaM1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: 1. Your file is probably not in a valid JSON format. 2. There is no need to call `close()` when using `with`.

Comment: This basically means its not a valid json.

Comment: Also, it's easier just to pass the file object directly to `json.load` (note the lack of s) without reading from the file.

Comment: There is a syntax error in line 1 column 1 (perhaps a comment?).

Comment: @DeanFenster  i had check the file text in jsonlint.com and it says that it is ok

Comment: @DeepSpace above comment

Comment: @Humbalan i had also checked it without s and i get some other errors

Comment: You should simply post the file content in your question

Comment: @DeepSpace i couldnt cause it was too big around 200000 lines

Comment: As DeepSpace said: pleas post the json file. Post just the first lines since the error is there.